# How can I have a code executed every time index is hit?

Tags: ember.js

How can I have a bit of code executed whenever `/` route is visited?

I have this now:

```
App.indexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    showFront: function () {
        alert("zzz");
    }
});
```

But I am stuck. How can I make it actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`beforeModel`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel) and [`setupController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) hooks to execute code when a route is loaded.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('posts', { path: '/posts' }, function() {});
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel
  beforeModel: function() {
    console.log("beforeModel fired");
  },

  // http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    console.log("setupController fired");
  },

  model: function(){
    // resolve the promise after a short delay
    return Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function(){
        resolve(true);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
});
```

`beforeModel` will fire, as the name suggests, before the model is loaded and `setupController` will fire after the model has loaded. The example in the JSBin uses a delayed loading model to demonstrate the difference.

This example shows the hooks being used for `App.Post` route, but you can use this on `App.ApplicationRoute` if you want to have code execute when loading the default route.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1476/edit)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define a route, and then call a function on it.

Read how here:

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Comment: This is not working: App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        $('#authentication').show();
    }
});